# Display suggested search result on search page if search result is empty

Tags: search

There are any way or module to display search result from suggested keyword on search page if search result is empty. just like google search, But result should come from my Apache solr system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Search API Spellcheck](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_spellcheck) module might be a starting point. It interfaces with the [Search API Solr](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) module.

Hope it helps,